# POST request hangs at "pending"

Tags: asp.net, post

I have a `room` and that room contains zero or more `devices`. Then I have a controller, `RoomController`. Here's a simplified version of the controller:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Room))]
public IHttpActionResult Postroom(NewRoom newRoom)
{
    ...
    Room room = new Room();
    room.building_id = newRoom.building_id;
    ...and soforth...

    if(newRoom.devices != null)
    {
        foreach (DeviceNew newDevice in newRoom.devices)
        {
            Device device = db.Devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.id == newDevice.id);
            room.Devices.Add(device);
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(room);
}
```

The controller works. The `room` is created, as are any attached `devices`. Sadly, the `POST` request never returns anything *if there are devices* included in the request. That is, in Chrome dev tools, the request remains "pending" forever.

If there *aren't* any devices, the request returns `200`, as expected.

Again, the controller *works*, even with `devices` included. The records are created. The route just doesn't return `Ok` the way it should.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The `Room` model (simplified):

```
namespace TheThing.Models_Database
{
    using System;
    ...

    public partial class Room
    {
        public Room()
        {
            Devices = new HashSet<Device>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `Device` model (simplified):

```
namespace TheThing.Models_Database
{
    using System;
    ...

    public partial class Device
    {
        public Device()
        {
            ...
            Rooms = new HashSet<Room>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an ajax request?

Comment: Yes. Originating from an angular project, but the result is the same via Postman or similar.

Comment: Sounds like it is having trouble serializing the Room object. Can you post details about that object?

Comment: Done. I didn't include everything, because both models are fairly sprawling. The relationship between the two should be clear?

Comment: Looks like you have a serialization infinite loop with your parent/child relationship.  When serializing the Room it looks as the Devices.  But they have Rooms which creates an infinite loop.  Here is a similar post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282185/errorserializing-entity-framework-class